# Iterate through pairwise row combinations in for loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate through my for loop by including all pairwise row comparisons.

Create a small, sample dataframe:

```
group    <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
distance <- c(709, 2283, 5515, 3035, 4471)
long     <- c(20.5, 29.4, -14.3, 9.85, -5.5)
lat      <- c(-19.6, 1.6, 10.9, 2.3, 7.5)
df       <- data.frame(group, distance, long, lat)
> df
  group distance  long   lat
1     A      709  20.5 -19.6
2     B     2283  29.4   1.6
3     C     5515 -14.3  10.9
4     D     3035  9.85   2.3
5     E     4471  -5.5   7.5
```

Create a matrix of indices of all row comparisons using `combn`:

```
combination <- combn(nrow(df), 2)
> combination
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

Here is my failed attempt to iterate through the pairwise row comparisons in my loop:

```
library(geosphere) ##load package for distVincentyEllipsoid function
out <- data.frame() ##initialize dataframe

for(i in combination[1,]) {
  for(j in combination[2,]) {
  P0 <- df[i, c("long", "lat")]
  x0 <- df[i, "long"]
  y0 <- df[i, "lat"]
  r0 <- df[i, "distance"]
  P1 <- df[j, c("long", "lat")]
  x1 <- df[j, "long"]
  y1 <- df[j, "lat"]
  r1 <- df[j, "distance"]
  d  <- abs(distVincentyEllipsoid(
      P1,
      P0,
      a = 6378137,
      b = 6356752.3142,
      f = 1 / 298.257223563
    ) / 1000)
  a  <- (r0 ^ 2 - r1 ^ 2 + d ^ 2) / (2 * d)
  h  <- (r0 ^ 2 - a ^ 2) ^ 2
  x2 <- x0 + a * (x1 - x0) / d
  y2 <- y0 + a * (y1 - y0) / d
  x3.1 <- x2 + h * (y1 - y0) / d
  y3.1 <- y2 + h * (x1 - x0) / d
  x3.2 <- x2 - h * (y1 - y0) / d
  y3.2 <- y2 - h * (x1 - x0) / d
  locations <- cbind(x3.1, y3.1, x3.2, y3.2)
  out <- rbind(out, locations)
  }
}
out
```

I have also tried `outer` and `apply`, but because my for loop as a function is multiple lines, I could not get it to work.

Here's how I want the output to look for one row pair, in the form of dataframe `locations`:

```
P0 <- df[df$group == "A", c("long", "lat")] 
x0 <- df[df$group == "A", "long"]
y0 <- df[df$group == "A", "lat"]
r0 <- df[df$group == "A", "distance"] 

P1 <- df[df$group == "B", c("long", "lat")] 
x1 <- df[df$group == "B", "long"]
y1 <- df[df$group == "B", "lat"]
r1 <- df[df$group == "B", "distance"] 

d  <- abs(distVincentyEllipsoid(P1, P0, a = 6378137, b = 6356752.3142, f = 1 / 298.257223563) / 1000)
a  <- (r0 ^ 2 - r1 ^ 2 + d ^ 2) / (2 * d)
h  <- (r0 ^ 2 - a ^ 2) ^ 2
x2 <- x0 + a * (x1 - x0) / d
y2 <- y0 + a * (y1 - y0) / d
x3.1 <- x2 + h * (y1 - y0) / d
y3.1 <- y2 + h * (x1 - x0) / d
x3.2 <- x2 - h * (y1 - y0) / d
y3.2 <- y2 - h * (x1 - x0) / d
locations <- cbind(x3.1, y3.1, x3.2, y3.2)

> locations
           x3.1      y3.1        x3.2       y3.2
[1,] 1243177033 521899766 -1243176990 -521899800
```

Because my real dataset contains many more row pairs, doing this by hand would take a lot of time and many lines of code.

Comment: `combn` has a `FUN=` argument where you can access each part of the combination, e.g.: `combn(1:3, m=2, FUN=\(x) x[1] + x[2])`

Comment: @thelatemail so you are saying it should be ```for(combn(nrow(df), 2, FUN=\(x) x[1] + x[2])) {``` ?

Comment: Potentially simpler approach, just feeding the coordinates in to create a distance matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013603/6851825.  e.g. `geodist::geodist(df[,c("lat","long")], measure = "vincenty")`

Comment: @JonSpring That is the goal of the contents of the loop, to use known Long/Lat and great circle distances to find the an unknown Long/Lat origin location, via the Intersection of two great circles: https://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/. I have a dataset with distances, but I don't know what location the researcher used as the origin location. Because TWO great circles is common, I am going through the pairs of nearby locations I have to create candidate Long/Lats of the origin and hopefully there will be a consensus. To make it efficient, I want to iterate through the pairs.

Comment: @simpson - no, I'm saying you can access the equivalent of your `i` and `j` inside the loops by just calling `combn` - all the looping is already taken care of by the `FUN=` argument:  `combn(1:3, m=2, FUN=\(x) {i <- x[1]; j <- x[2]; print(c(i,j))}  )`

Comment: @thelatemail Okay, putting the contents of the loop in place of ```print(c(i,j))``` worked to iterate through the pairs of rows. But even with ```out <- rbind(out, locations)``` as my last line in the function, how do I store the results of the iterations in object ```out```? Just assigning ```combn```... to an object ```out``` creates a weird list.

Comment: You don't need to `rbind` the output - just return `locations` at the end of the `FUN=` function. You are returning `locations` for each iteration inside `combn` and then you can assign the whole thing to `out`.

Comment: @thelatemail Removing that last line ```out <- rbind(out, locations)``` and assigning ```combn``` and its function contents to an object ```out``` creates an array with dimensions 1:4:10. The dimensions 4 (columns) and 10 (rows) are correct, so how do I constrain ```out``` to just be a dataframe with 10 rows and 4 columns instead of the array? Do I ```unlist``` it?

Comment: Try something like `matrix(out, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)` and see if that makes it as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, @thelatemail for the steps to answer my question. Here is the answer to my question using the dataframe `df` from the question:

```
library(geosphere) ##load package for distVincentyEllipsoid function

locations <-  combn(nrow(df), 2, FUN=\(x) {i <- x[1]; j <- x[2];   
  P0 <- df[i, c("long", "lat")]
  x0 <- df[i, "long"]
  y0 <- df[i, "lat"]
  r0 <- df[i, "distance"]
  P1 <- df[j, c("long", "lat")]
  x1 <- df[j, "long"]
  y1 <- df[j, "lat"]
  r1 <- df[j, "distance"]
  d  <- abs(distVincentyEllipsoid(
      P1,
      P0,
      a = 6378137,
      b = 6356752.3142,
      f = 1 / 298.257223563
    ) / 1000)                  ##d in km
  a  <- (r0 ^ 2 - r1 ^ 2 + d ^ 2) / (2 * d)
  h  <- (r0 ^ 2 - a ^ 2) ^ 2
  x2 <- x0 + a * (x1 - x0) / d
  y2 <- y0 + a * (y1 - y0) / d
  x3.1 <- x2 + h * (y1 - y0) / d
  y3.1 <- y2 + h * (x1 - x0) / d
  x3.2 <- x2 - h * (y1 - y0) / d
  y3.2 <- y2 - h * (x1 - x0) / d
  locations <- cbind(x3.1, y3.1, x3.2, y3.2)}  ) ##this creates an array

locations <- matrix(locations, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE) ##change the array into a matrix
```